# Checking the method to compare value of various integrals

Tags: integration

If I is the greatest of
$$
=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x} \cos ^{2} x d x, I_{2}=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^{2}} \cos ^{2} x d x, I_{3}=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^{2}} d x, I_{4}=\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^{2} / 2} d x
$$ show that $I = I_4$.

> My progress : the problems seems impossible to do with exactly calculating the integrals so i tried using bound in all integrals . $I_3$ and $I_4$ can be easily compared as we know in $(0,1) {x^2} > \frac{x^2}{2}$ so ${-x^2} < \frac{-x^2}{2}$ always in (0,1), so $\int_{0}^{1} e^{-x^2}dx$ < $\int_{0}^{1} e^\frac{-x^2}{2}dx$ hence $I_3<I_4$ . But i am unable to show that with $I_1$ and $I_2$  with $I_4$ can anyone please help .

Comment: Try using the mean value theorem for integrals and looking for bounds to derivatives

Answer (score 2):

Important : if in $(a,b)$, $f(x)\leq g(x)$ for all $x\in (a,b)$, then $\int_a^b f(x)dx \leq \int_a^b g(x)dx$. 
 
In (0,1),  $x^2 <x$ so $$e^{-x^2}>e^{-x}>e^{-x}cos^2x$$$$e^{-x^2}>e^{-x^2}cos^2x$$

Also, $\frac{x^2}{2}<x^2$ so $$e^{-\frac{x^2}{2}}>e^{-x^2}$$ Combining the above statements, the result follows. 
 **NOTE**

1. If $a>b$ then $e^a>e^b$ because $e^x$ increases monotonically over $\mathbb R$ so $e^{-b}>e^{-a}$.
2. $cos^2x \in (0,1)$ for $ x \in (0,1)$ so $a > a cos^2x$.